# Gathering static messages in one file?

Tags: c#

I have a solution with more then one projects. Is there a way i can create one file that is not compiled like resx file and is accessable from all the other projects? Or do i have to create a file (of what type) for each project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at this topic: [Adding or linking existing files to a project in Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234)

You can link existing file between different projects.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way i can create one file that is not compiled like resx file

Set file action not to compile, that simple. Check the file properties.

> and is accessable from all the other projects?

Put it onto the solutoin folder then dont ADD it to the projects (which copies it) but LINK it. The Add button in the dialog is a drop down - you can link a file to multiple projects instead of adding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an alias by using the 'Add existing file' context menu item alternative and then 'Add As Link'; referring the original file to your other projects.